# Can I transfer ethers from user to a contract by pressing a button and accept in metamask?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, web3-providers

I am learning solidity and react and for that I want create a web platform for Social Events.
The events have a id, adress (owner of the event), price and the page looks like this:
[image]

I am connected to the page with metamask using web3js. And my idea is when the user press the blue button, the user send ethers (the price of the event) to the contract with user permission.

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily create send promise that will pop up the metamask or wallet being connected to the interface using `sendTransaction` method of web3.

Eg.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: 'fromAddress_from_metamask',
    to: 'EOA_OR_contract_address',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.then(function(receipt){
    ...
});
```

You can view details about that in [web3 doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction).